# Parallel requests in cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to make parallel `request`s in cypress. I define a command for that:

```js
const resetDb = () => {
  const apiUrl = `${Cypress.config().baseUrl}/api`;
  Cypress.Promise.all([
    cy.request(`${apiUrl}/group/seed/resetDb`),
    cy.request(`${apiUrl}/auth/seed/resetDb`),
    cy.request(`${apiUrl}/email/seed/resetDb`),
  ]);
};
Cypress.Commands.add('resetDb', resetDb);
```

However, it is still making those requests in sequence. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem using task in Cypress, which allows you to use nodejs API.

In the plugins index file, I define a task as follows:

```js
const fetch = require('isomorphic-unfetch');

 module.exports = on => {
  on('task', {
    resetDb() {
      const apiUrl = `http://my.com/api`;
      return Promise.all([
        fetch(`${apiUrl}/group/seed/resetDb`),
        fetch(`${apiUrl}/auth/seed/resetDb`),
        fetch(`${apiUrl}/email/seed/resetDb`),
      ]);
    },
  });
};
```

The it can be used as follows:

```js
before(() => {
  return cy.task('resetDb');
});
```